# strange C++ warning

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

certain compiler, derived from EDG gives me `expression has no effect` warning
on this line

```
return 1 << ((i == j) + (k == l) + ((i == k) & (j == l)));
```

values are runtime values, compiler does not know them.

```
return 1 << (((i == k) & (j == l))); // no warning here
return 1 << ((i == j) + (k == l)); //or here
```

am I missing something or is compiler confused?

the code segment below does not have warning.
if a change parameters to constant reference, warning come back

```
    //static int symmetry(const int &i, const int &j, const int &k, const int &l) {
    static int symmetry(int i, int j, int k, int l) {
        // return 1 << ((i == j) + (k == l));
        //return 1 << (((i == k) && (j == l)) + (k != l));
        return 1 << ((i == j) + (k == l) + ((i == k) && (j == l)));
    }
```

the program is correct even with warning.  possibility that program is wrong is very very small this particular code segment would throw calculations off

thank you for your time, I am going to assume compiler is making mistake here.
just in case you find similar problem, compiler is nvcc, NVIDIA gpu cuda compiler

Comment: Are you sure that the compiler can not the values? Its hard to tell without more context.

Comment: what is the type of i, j, k, l and so on.

Comment: @Martin absolutely, they come from dynamic array at runtime

Comment: Argh, `l` that looks like `1`.

Comment: With absolutely no idea what its supposed to actually do, I would break it into its component parts, and insert some trace statements to see if everything is evaluating to what you would expect it to be.  `bool ij = (i == j); cout << i << " " << j << " << ij << endl;` and so forth.

Comment: There's a difference between the '`&`' used in the main part of the question and the '`&&`' used in the complete function.  Whether it actually matters is more debatable - but it is definitely a notational (and notional) difference.  Which is the one with the complaint?

Comment: I can't force gcc to generate a warning on any of those, and the logic [while overly complex] seems sound.  My guess is you're either mistaken about the source of the warning, you're not providing actual code, or there's a compiler bug.

Comment: &Jon I was playing with various combinations to find difference.
the operators do not matter, they both generate warning

Answer (score 4):

I started to prove that there were transitivities that could be optimized to constants; I couldn't. As anonymous noted, the prior code could provide constraints that the compiler uses to degenerate the expressions to constants.

But, when in doubt, print a truth table:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, k, l, x;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    for(k = 0; k < 2; k++)
    for(l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
        x = ((i == j) + (k == l) + ((i == k) & (j == l)));
        printf("%d %d %d %d: %d, %d, %d -> %d\n", i, j, k, l, (i == j),
                (k == l), ((i == k) & (j == l)), x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which yields:

```
0 0 0 0: 1, 1, 1 -> 3
0 0 0 1: 1, 0, 0 -> 1
0 0 1 0: 1, 0, 0 -> 1
0 0 1 1: 1, 1, 0 -> 2
0 1 0 0: 0, 1, 0 -> 1
0 1 0 1: 0, 0, 1 -> 1
0 1 1 0: 0, 0, 0 -> 0
0 1 1 1: 0, 1, 0 -> 1
1 0 0 0: 0, 1, 0 -> 1
1 0 0 1: 0, 0, 0 -> 0
1 0 1 0: 0, 0, 1 -> 1
1 0 1 1: 0, 1, 0 -> 1
1 1 0 0: 1, 1, 0 -> 2
1 1 0 1: 1, 0, 0 -> 1
1 1 1 0: 1, 0, 0 -> 1
1 1 1 1: 1, 1, 1 -> 3
```

Under both gcc and g++ 4.4.3 and no warnings with `-Wall` set. Even with i, j, k, and l declared `const`, the compiler doesn't see `x` as invariant. The compiler seems either transcendentally smart or is broken.

Comment: I tried remarkably similar code (over the range 1..4 instead of 0..2) and agree with your basic result - using both GCC 4.2.1 and GCC 4.5.1.  And it also makes no odds in this case whether the operator is '`&&`' or '`&`' - the result is the same.  That is not normally the case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mis-transcription of `&&` which, as you note, is equivalent between two comparison operators which have no side effects.

Comment: thank you.  for time being I am going to assume compiler is broken/overly cautious.I am able to defeat warnings, and it is good enough for me

Answer (score 1):

What is the code before this expression?

The compiler could be finding an optimisation in your function that means your condition always evaluates to the same answer each time. It sounds like the compiler is telling you that your logic is flawed somewhere and you could just "return 0;" or "return 1;" to have the same effect.

Comment: We need to know how the funtion is being called. If it's being inlined within a different section of your code and you've set i = j = k = l in that context, the function will be optimized out completely.

Can you give us a copy of the "by reference" function which does generate the warning?

Comment: thanks for your time.  I think I am just going to assume compiler is making a mistake in judgment from others people feedback